# PHP system() works for some commands, but not all

Tags: php, gcc

I have a web server being hosted on a Raspberry Pi B+, running Raspbian. I always have a php "shell" that i can use, but it seems that mine might be messed up somehow. It is an html textarea, with the `name="phptorun"`, and the action file just does `eval($_POST['phptorun']);`

Since I just have my RPi tucked under a table with no display, I use my phone alot to access the command line.

My question:

When i run something like `system("ls");` i get output and the contents of the working directory is displayed. I am working on a C "compiler" (it just uses the command line `gcc`) but when i do `system("gcc");`
i get no output at all. i know that the command gcc does put out output, because i have done it before on a different computer.

So why is `system("gcc");` not working?

And if gcc isnt installed, wouldnt i get output, just an error?

Comment: Execute it like `system($command, $return)` and check what's in the `$return` variable.

Comment: @Ferenczy it just output "4", why did that happen?

Comment: I don't know, so why not ask [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+return+code+4&oq=linux+return+code+4)? According to [this page](http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Errors/unix_system_errors.html) it's **Interrupted system call**. That's a good start  for a further investigation.

Comment: You accepted my answer, but to help others it would be good if you can describe what exactly was your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get more information, it's possible that `gcc` outputs something to the `STDERR` for example, which you're missing when you use the [`system`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) function.

Better try to use the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function:

```
 exec("gcc 2>&1", $output, $return_code);
```

Explanation:

- `gcc 2>&1` redirects `STDERR` output to the `STDOUT`
- `STDOUT` is captured into the `$output` variable
- command return code is in the variable `$return_code`